# Finite abelian groups are solvable

Tags: group-theory

I know that finite abelian groups are solvable, because it means $  G^{(1)}=1.$ I also know that a group is solvable if you have a tower of 
$1=G_{s} \ \triangleleft  \ G_{s-1} \ \triangleleft \ \dots \ \triangleleft \ G_1 \triangleleft \ G_0 = G$  with $G_i/G_{i+1}$ cyclic.

My intuition for the tower would be to write $1=G^{(1)} \ \triangleleft \ G$ but I don't see how $G/G^{(1)}$ is cyclic.

thanks

Comment: The condition about the series of groups with cyclic subgroup applies only to finite solvable groups. An infinite solvable group does not necessarily have such a series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G/1$ is not necessarily cyclic.

However, the [classification theorem for finite abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group#Classification) tells us that we can write
$$ G = C_1 \times C_2 \times C_3 \times \dots \times C_n,$$
where $C_1, C_2, C_3 , \dots , C_n$ are all cyclic.

So we can take
$$ G_n = 1, \ \ \ \ \  G_{n-1} = C_1, \ \ \ \ \ G_{n-2} = C_1 \times C_2, \ \ \ \ \ G_{n-3} = C_1 \times C_2 \times C_3 , \ \ \ \ \   \dots  \ \ \ \ \ G_0 = G.$$

Then, for each $i$, we have
$$ G_{i}/G_{i+1} = C_{n-i},$$
which is cyclic.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I didn't understand your question correctly, I think you got your definitions mixed up.

A solvable group is a group which has a subnormal "tower" with **abelian** quotients, not necessarily cyclic.

In that case, it is clear that for a finite abelian group $G$ the tower you suggested is good, as the quotient is $G$ which is abelian.

Comment: To be fair, I've seen both definitions being used (cyclic quotients and abelian quotients) - and of course they both work. But +1 for your answer nonetheless. :)

Comment: I was actually not aware that the cyclic definition exists and equivalent. Thanks!